# Regex or LINQ to match pattern using C#

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I am writing small program to extract Tv series Name with its season.
I have following text string list.

```
Entourage Season 3 Part 2 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
Entourage Season 4 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
Entourage Season 5 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
Entourage Season 8 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
The Walking Dead: Season Four | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
The Walking Dead: Season Three| 5 NIGHT HIRE |
The Walking Dead: Season Two | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
The Walking Dead: Season One | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
Game Of Thrones: Season One| 5 NIGHT HIRE |
Game Of Thrones: Season Two | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
```

I need to obtain TV series name group by season.

**Entourage**

```
Season 3
Season 4
Season 5
Season 8
```

**The Walking Dead**

```
Season One
Season Two
Season Three
Season Four
```

**Game Of Thrones**

```
Season One
Season Two
```

I have regex to match season, but it didn't work.

> Match match = Regex.Match(this.Content,@"(?:^|(?:[.!?]\s))(?Season \w+)")

I Need Help using regualr expression in C# or using LINQ query.

Comment: There is no question here; you are giving us a task to do for you. That's not how SO works.

Comment: brother you'r asking to do the task for you..

Comment: sorry brother, i only need a line of regular expression ( not whole code) , which i was not able to write. I think i need to learn regex pattern. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This linqpad script:

```
var text = @"
   Entourage Season 3 Part 2 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   Entourage Season 4 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   Entourage Season 5 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   Entourage Season 8 | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   The Walking Dead: Season Four | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   The Walking Dead: Season Three| 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   The Walking Dead: Season Two | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   The Walking Dead: Season One | 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   Game Of Thrones: Season One| 5 NIGHT HIRE |
   Game Of Thrones: Season Two | 5 NIGHT HIRE |";
var matches = text.Split(new[]{"\r\n","\n"},0)
                  .Select(l => Regex.Match(l, @"^\s*(?<title>.+?)(?<season>Season \w+)"));
var data = matches.Where (m => m.Success)
                  .Select (m => new {Title = m.Groups["title"].Value.Trim(':',' '),Season = m.Groups["season"].Value});

data.GroupBy(d => d.Title)
    .Select (g => new {g.First().Title,Seasons = g.Select (x => x.Season)}).Dump();
```

Returns this:

[image]

Comment: thanks, the regex pattern ^\s*(?<title>.+?)(?<season>Season \w+) work like a charm.Thanks for your output.